# Vue js not rendering image with base64 or binary data from Express API response

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, axios

My Vue js component receives images via express API call as base64 or raw binary data, but it does not display (render) it.

I can see the image data in the variable given to img src, but for some reason it never renders it, only showing the "broken image icon".

[Screenshot of broken image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzpsY.png)

This is the frontend component layout:
`<img src="srcimg" v-if="srcimg">`

The data mounted and watch functions call the async getsrcimg function which makes the Express API call:

```
  data () {
    return {
      srcimg: null,
...
  mounted () {
    if (this.name) {
      this.getsrcimg(this.name)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    name: function () {
      if (this.name) {
        this.getsrcimg(this.name)
      }
    }
  },
```

And the function that receives the image via api:

```
  async getsrcimg (name) {
    try {
      var getImgRes = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/get_img?img_path=' + name)
      const { data } = getImgRes
      this.srcimg = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      this.message = err.response.data.error
    }
   }
```

The server backend function:

```
app.post('/get_img', (req, res) => {
  var img_path = __dirname + req.query.img_path  
  var fs = require('fs');  
  const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(img_path);
  const base64 = new Buffer.from(bitmap).toString("base64");
  res.send(base64);  // Send base64 instead of the raw file binary
});
```

I can see in the console log, as well as display the `this.srcimg` data available in this format:
`data:image/png;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCg...`

But still, the HTML img element does not display the image.

I know the image is being sent correctly because I can see it in the browser inspect Network response preview so it probably is an issue within Vue frontend.

I have also tried to send the image raw binary data from server using `res.sendFile` and then loading it in the frontend using:

```
     const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/png'})
     var imgName = 'image_name_example'
     var file = new File([blob], imgName, { type: 'image/png' })
     let reader = new FileReader()
     reader.readAsDataURL(file)
     reader.addEventListener('load', this.processReaderIMG, false)
...
    processReaderIMG: function (readerData) {
      this.srcimg = readerData.target.result
    }
```

This also gives me the image data but the img element does not display it still.

Any help would be much much appreciated!

Comment: `<img :src="srcimg" v-if="srcimg">`

Comment: obligatory warning, one could use /get_img to load any file, i.e `/get_img?img_path=../.env` then trivially base64 decode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really is your frontend component:

```html
<img src="srcimg" v-if="srcimg" />
```

, it attempts to render `"srcimg"`, **the** *actual* **string**, instead of the contents of the reactive variable named `srcimg`.
And `"srcimg"` is not a valid source. It's not a url and it's not binary data.

You probably want to use `:src` instead of `src`:

```html
<img :src="srcimg" v-if="srcimg" />
```

, shorthand for

```html
<img v-bind:src="srcimg" v-if="srcimg" />
```

Docs: [v-bind](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind).

---

If the above is not the issue, test that the binary data is valid (manually).
Other possible causes:

- the binary data might contain line breaks which break the HTML (highly improbable, but worth a check)
- the response has a different encoding than your page
- the response is already prefixed with `'data:image/png;base64,'`

If everything fails, perhaps you could share the exact response of the server. There has to be something wrong with it, which you're missing.

Comment: That was a good catch! I missed the : in :src for sure. I fixed it but still I got the same issue. So I backtracked to previous attempts on base64 binary that failed when I didnt have the :src, and now it worked. Thank you so much for the detailed answer!!!